# Can't accesss cv from CiviUnitTestCase::createExternalAPI in buildkit environment

Tags: civimail, developer, testing

I'm QAing https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9255 and trying to run a couple of relevant test locally:

```
~/src/civicrm-buildkit/build/qa/sites/all/modules/civicrm$ tools/scripts/phpunit api_v3_JobProcessMailingTest --filter testConcurrency
```

I'm getting the following error output from each time the test uses CiviUnitTestCase::createExternalAPI to call the API:

```
[is_error] => 1
[error_message] => External API returned malformed response.
[trace] => Array
    (
        [code] => 127
        [stdout] => 
        [stderr] => sh: 1: cv: not found

    )
```

cv api Contact.get works as expected from the same directory.

Any ideas on what to do next to debug? I get why the test wants to do things concurrently, but my eyes start glazing over (only a little!) when I start looking at civicrm/Civi/API/ExternalBatch.php and I'm hoping I might have overlooked something 'obvious'.

Comment: I tried doing a bit of troubleshooting, mainly in `tests/phpunit/CiviTest/bootstrap.php`, but I'm not convinced that's the right place.  In any case, this DOES work for me.

Comment: Hmm, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717897/popen-fails-with-sh-command-not-found) was brought to us by the letter `^A`, which might be relevant (CiviCRM uses this character as a value separator). Asker closes with _"I would encourage anyone with a similar problem to look for hidden characters in the string used with popen()."_

Answer (score 2):

The error message says `sh: 1: cv not found`, so the symptom here is that the `proc_open()` call is unable to find the executable `cv`.

It looked like the place to check this should be `cv()` function in [tests/phpunit/CiviTest/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/CiviTest/bootstrap.php#L27) ... but I wasn't able to get that to work.

Having investigated, I suspect that this may be an issue in `\Civi\API\ExternalBatch`. [In that class's constructor](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/ExternalBatch.php#L45),

```
$this->env = $_ENV;
```

At this point in the tests, `$_ENV = ['CIVICRM_UF' => 'UnitTests']`. There is no path here, and the call to `cv` fails. Manually inserting a `PATH` into `$_ENV` here does restore the ability to call `cv`, but then fails with a further "malformed response" error, "Failed to determine INI file path.".

This must be working on tests.civicrm.org, so perhaps it's a configuration issue that affects both our test environments?

- [`civicrm/cv#1` is this issue?](https://github.com/civicrm/cv/issues/1)
- Tim suggests it [may relate to Debian's default variables_order being GPCS no EGPCS](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18796)
- Suggests: https://gist.github.com/totten/cf76679b4fabdae4c86e06f8c0988b23